# quick jquery href question

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack...">1</a>`

I want to remove the anchor and replace it with an onClick jquery event handler like this:

```
$(myselector).click(function () { ... });
```

I'm wondering what to put in the ... since this is a javascript call.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(myselector).click(function(){ ...; return false });
```

Comment: What does return false do? Do I need it?

Comment: return false makes jQuery forget about the actual href and it won't use it. Why use the 'href' then? Well because an a tag is no link without a href, so people without a mouse can still access it via tabindex or so :P

Comment: @frenchie: If you read the other answers, you would have the answer to that before you asked.

Comment: @Orbling: well i guess my sexy appearance (see profilepic) distracted him :)

Comment: Not knocking your answer, it was just fine, only the explanation had already been covered elsewhere for the code you demonstrated nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You still need an `href` in your markup otherwise it won't be clickable - `#` is the normal value:

```
<a href="#" id="myId">1</a>
```

And in your Javascript:

```
$('#myId').click(function () {
    __doPostBack...
    return false;
});
```

You need the `return false` at the end otherwise your browser will still try to follow the `href`.

Comment: +1, but it doesn't need to be an id, it could also be any other selector.

Comment: yes, of course it could - this is just a concrete example for those less familiar with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If your selector matches the anchor itself, then you can just use the `.click()` method and ensure it returns false, that will prevent the default execution of the `href` value.

You could remove the anchor entirely by using `.unwrap()`.

Answer (score 0):

you would do:

```
$(myselector).click(function () { __doPostBack... });
```

and if the `$(myselector)` was still an anchor tag you would also need a `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

`return false;` probably does the trick, but you should be using [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)...

```
$(myselector).click(function(e) {
  // ...
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```